# I'm using strapi and next.js i'm able fetch data at first but when i change data in strapi the data is not updated

Tags: next.js, fetch, strapi

I'm using strapi and next.js i'm able fetch data at first but when i change data in strapi the data is not updated. It takes the data when i first build it,  i change the data in strapi animport React from 'react';

--updated answer

```
import React from 'react';
import Blogs from './components/Blogs';
import Categories from './components/Categories';
import Image from 'next/image';

async function fetchBlogs() {
    const options = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
        },
        next: { revalidate: 1 } // Time-based revalidation every hour
    };

    try {
        const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/blogs?populate=*", options);
        const response = await res.json();
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

async function fetchCategories() {
    const options = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.STRAPI_API_TOKEN}`,
        },
        next: { revalidate: 1 } // Time-based revalidation every hour
    };

    try {
        const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/categories", options);
        const response = await res.json();
        return response;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

export default async function Home() {
    const categories = await fetchCategories();
    const blogs = await fetchBlogs();

    return (
        <div> 
            <Categories categories={categories} />
            <Blogs blogs={blogs} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, using `fetch` within Next.js will also populate the cache, which is reused for subsequent requests to optimize the network usage. Even if the data changes in the backend, Next.js will by default use the cache first, meaning it will display the previously fetched data.

There are ways to manually refresh you data, either based on an event (e.g. refresh button) or based on time. I invite you to read the docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#revalidating-data).

Time based example:

```
fetch('https://...', { next: { revalidate: 3600 } })
```

Manual trigger example:

```
export default async function Page() {
  const res = await fetch('https://...', { next: { tags: ['collection'] } })
  const data = await res.json()
  // ...
}


// In another file
'use server'
 
import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache'
 
export default async function action() {
  revalidateTag('collection')
}
```

Alternatively, you can fully opt-out of the caching if necessary.

Side note: you misspelled `Bearer` writing `Berer`.